Swapped on Metamask, usdt out but the transaction failed, coins are gone
I tried to swap usdt to another coin on Ethereum using metamask swap, I approved the swap with $5000 usdt but it transferred out all of my usdt, while the transaction went failed due to low gas fee, now I can’t receive the new coin nor usdt. What should I do?
Txn: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe165edc34d99cc266de83839378eafa1622cfe7308eee40e1b660c04f5598b7d
Usdt got transferred out:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1f36441a75f028bac20903eee02586a62e90c90e6a749c6ed606a7b0869f7497

It seems you was hacked sir, it sent USDT to Fake_Phising address
